# Confusion regarding the Cauchy-Euler equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

`In my textbook it says that:`

> An equation of the form $$a_2 x^2 \frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}x^2}+a_1 x \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}+a_0 y=f(x)$$ is called an Euler or Cauchy equation. It can be reduced to a linear equation with constant coefficients by changing the independent variable from $x$ to $z$ where $$x=e^z\tag{A}$$ For then we have $$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}z}=x\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\tag{1}$$ and $$x^2\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}x^2}=\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}z^2}-\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}z}\tag{2}$$

I would like to know how $(1)$ and $(2)$ were derived.

I think I can derive $(1)$ as follows:

From $(\mathrm{A})$ 
$$z=\ln x\implies \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\ln x \right)=\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}x}\implies \frac{1}{x}=\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}x}\implies \frac{1}{\mathrm{d}z}=\frac{x}{\mathrm{d}x}\implies \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}z}=x\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$$ as required.

But I have no idea how to derive $(2)$.

Could someone please show me the derivation of $(2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=e^z$. (A)

Then

$$x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=x^2\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dy}{dx})=x^2\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{dz})=x^2(\frac{1}{x}\frac{d}{dx}\frac{dy}{dz}-\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{dy}{dz})$$
$$=x^2(\frac{1}{x}\frac{d}{dz}\frac{dz}{dx}\frac{dy}{dz}-\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{dy}{dz})=x^2\times\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{d^2y}{dz^2}-x^2\times\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{dy}{dz}$$
$$=\frac{d^2y}{dz^2}-\frac{dy}{dz}$$
By (1).